# Javascript not executed on Firefox, working on Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

starting this morning I'm having difficulties executing Javascript code on Firefox. This simple code example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('HEAD!');
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.write('<p>BODY</p>');
    </script>   
</body>
```

works as expected on

- Safari - Version 7.0.2 (9537.74.9)
- Chrome - Version 33.0.1750.149

but NOT on Firefox - Version 27.0.1. I'm getting a blank page here, page source looks good.

Firebug says:

> No Javascript on this page

I've already

- checked the about:config => javascript.enabled true
- disabled all extensions and restarted Firefox
- restarted Apache/MAMP PRO (2.1.4) - doesn’t even work for me via intErnet, so this should be not related to MAMP (http://shoco.biz/test.html)
- restarted the computer (Mac OS X 10.9.2)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Comment: what are you getting?

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 27.0.1. Must be your browser settings or something like that.

Comment: Hey Olli,

I think the same discussion already available on Mozilla's forum http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=519837.. Hope this helps

Comment: Try this script in the head section on your browser.

Comment: @Ramkumar: in this topic the problem's been an extension - I've disabled all my extensions...

Comment: @Dot_NET Junior: tried that - same result, I'm only getting a blank page...

Comment: @Olli mein kampf? (LOL)

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl: *lol* - already changed...

Comment: @AMember: getting a blank page

Comment: Try opening firefox in _safe mode_  `help -> Restart with Add ons disabled` then reset everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening firefox in safe mode `help -> Restart with Add ons disabled` then reset everything